# simpleXML node access by index prob!em

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am receiving an XML response based on a request I place to a server and it does in fact return a valid set of results that I can dump on the screen using print_r()
Result set looks like this(edit: this is the exact structure of the file):

```
<root>  
     <main_node1>  
         <value1>one</value1>  
         <value2>two</value2>  
     </main_node1>  
     <main_node2>  
         <anothervalue>whatever</anothervalue>  
     </main_node2>  
     <recordset>  
        <record>  
            <value1>one</value1>  
            <value2>two</value2>  
        </reocrd>  
        <record>  
            <value1>one</value1>  
            <value2>two</value2>  
        </reocrd>  
        <record>  
            <value1>one</value1>  
            <value2>two</value2>  
        </reocrd>  
     </recordset>  
</root>
```

when I use the line:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlRequest);
$records = $xml->recordset->record;
```

I can walk through the $records array with a foreach loop without any problems however, when I try to access a specific record within the recordset using an index such as

```
$record = $xml->recordset->record[$index];
```

I am getting a NULL valeu back. I also tried to cast the result into an (array) with no success so far.

Every document I looked at regarding simpleXML says that it is possible to access the XML node by index, can someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong here?

Edit: so recordset is not the root of the document yet I am able to use the $xml->recordset->record notation to load a list of records in to my $records variable and print it out using the foreach loop.

Comment: Could you give a full example that fails? (The XML as well as the code you use, or some code similar to it for the sake of the example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my issue by using

```
$records = $xml->xpath('//record');
```

notation and I am now able to access any record by their index.

Thank you for trying, I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

You're not getting anything back because the 'recordset' node is the root of your $xml variable (not sure if I'm describing this correctly).

This should work:

```
<?php
    //Example xml, replace this with $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlRequest);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <recordset><record><value1>one</value1><value2>two</value2></record>
    <record><value1>one</value1><value2>two</value2></record>
    </recordset>');

    $record = $xml->record[0];
    print_r ($record);
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, without using xpath is:

Using this as base:

```
 $record = $xml->recordset->record[$index];
```

You got to make index as int, for some reason just receiving it does not work. So:

```
$index = trim($_GET['index']);
$index = intval($index);
```

Now this will work:

```
 $record = $xml->recordset->record[$index];
```

Best Regards,
RaphaelDDL